# Algorithm For Finding Greenwich Mean Sidereal Time Having Problems

Tags: physics

I have currently gotten an algorithm to work for finding the Julian Day for my current location, but when using this value to proceed in finding the Greenwich Mean Sidereal Time, I get some very funky numbers. Can anyone run this script and maybe determine where my calculations go wrong? Thanks.

```
#1/user/bin/python
import math
from time import gmtime, strftime

#Sidereal Time Program

#Julien Date Converter

seconds = (int(strftime("%S")) * .01)

JD1 = ((367 * (int(strftime("%Y")))) - ((7 * ((int(strftime("%Y")))
      + (((int(strftime("%m"))) + 9) / 12))) / 4)
      + ((275 * (int(strftime("%m")))) / 9) + (int(strftime("%d"))) + 1721013.5
      + ((int(strftime("%I")) + (seconds) + 4) / 24) - 0.5 + 0.5 + 1.46)

JD2 = ((367 * (int(strftime("%Y")))) - ((7 * ((int(strftime("%Y")))
      + (((int(strftime("%m"))) + 9) / 12))) / 4)
      + ((275 * (int(strftime("%m")))) / 9) + (int(strftime("%d"))) + 1721013.5
      + ((int(12) + 4) / 24) - 0.5 + 0.5 - 0.192361555)

H = JD1 - JD2
JD = JD2 + (H / 24)
D1 = JD1 - 2451545.0
D2 = JD2 - 2451545.0
T = D1 / 36525

GMST1 = 6.697374558 + (0.06570982441908 * D2) + (1.00273790935 * H) + (0.000026 * (T * T))

GMST2 = 18.697374558 + (24.06570982441908 * D1)

o =  125.04 - (0.052954 * D1)

L = 280.47 + (0.98565 * D1)

e = 23.4393 - (0.0000004 * D1)

x = 2 * L

sym = (-0.000319 * (math.sin (o))) - (0.000024 * (math.sin (x)))

eqeq = (sym * (math.cos (e)))

GAST1 = GMST1 + eqeq

GAST2 = GMST2 +eqeq

print (JD1)
print (T)
print (GAST1)
print (GAST2)
```

Edit: Here is the formula I am using: http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/GAST.php

Comment: What range should the output values be in?  I am familiar with those formulas but by no means expert in them.

Comment: Looking at [this](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/JulianDate.php), the value I get for JD1 (2456588.188...) doesn't match today (2456586.5).  Also, `math.sin` and the other functions use radians, and the formulas give `o`, `L`, and `e` in degrees.  Conversion is `o_rad = o*math.pi/180`.

Comment: Wow I didn't even realize that thanks! Do you think this will yield the correct Julian Day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that [this](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/contrib.html/lang/python/examples/sidereal/index.html) is a package that will do what you want.  See, e.g., [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/contrib.html/lang/python/examples/sidereal/SiderealTime-gst.html).

Comment: @Garrett, is sidereal.py working for you?  If so, please click the checkmark by the answer to accept it so others will know it's a good option.  Thanks!

Comment: No, unfortunately it did not work. I ended up using a couple other Python libraries though and I think I have solved my issue. Thanks for setting me on the right track though!

Comment: @Garrett - Glad to hear you got it going!  What did you wind up using?